# Spark Dataframe to SQL server storing wrong data for multiple records

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

I am seeing data correctly printed with `dataframe.show` , but in database it is storing previous value.

For example we have 3 records:

```
orderId| ItemSequence|OriginalId|price|groupId

dddeff |  1          |   201    | 1.5 |  8

dddeff |  2          |    202   | 2.5 |  3

dddeff |  3          |   203    | 3.0 |  9
```

Above data is showing correctly when we are printing to console using df.show, when it is persisting to database below are the values

```
**orderId| ItemSequence|OriginalId|price|groupId**

dddeff |  1  |         201   |   1.5  |  8

dddeff |  2  |         202   |    2.5 |  3

dddeff |  3  |         201   |    1.5 |  8
```

---

```
val orderItemDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
orderItemDF.show()
try {
  orderItemDF.write
    .mode(SaveMode.Append)
    .jdbc(dbURL,
          schema + "." + StreamingConstants.DIGL_ORD_ITM,
          connectionProperties = prop)
  return true
} catch {
  case e: Exception =>
    println("Error in DIGL_ORD_ITM processing:" + e.getMessage)
    return false
}
```

Please note that we are having unique constraint on orderId and ItemSequence
We are using Spark 2.0.2 with Scala 2.11 and jdk1.8.0_121-b13

Did someone face similar problem? any solution?

Comment: please update your question with dbURL details, and prop. And why are you using schema + "." + StreamingConstants.DIGL_ORD_ITM?

Comment: Why are the JDBC connection properties (table name, url, etc.) relevant?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here. Are there two unique constraints, one on `orderId` and other other on `ItemSequence`, or is there a single constraint on the pair `(orderId, ItemSequence)`? I'd definitely consider these constraints as the source of your issue.

Comment: It is single constraint on the pair (orderId, ItemSequence) and issue happens randomly